# Retrieve data from List<Map>

Tags: java, parsing, java-stream

I subscribe to a topic using a Stream `Stream<Map<String, Object>> sub = ipfs.pubsub.sub(topic)` and after that I collect it to a List which will collect the first two results `List<Map> results = sub.limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());` and will later get parsed 
by `results.stream().filter(s->s.containsKey("data")).forEach(System.out::println);` returning the following output

```
{from=EiANvs2UUz/KwtJhTJIgOdUPvsNeVF74GczENrlC4UCFVQ==, data=SGVsbG8h, seqno=FaaJ6v+WW+g=, topicIDs=[demo134001007467618]}
{from=EiANvs2UUz/KwtJhTJIgOdUPvsNeVF74GczENrlC4UCFVQ==, data=RydkYXk=, seqno=FaaJ6v+WW+k=, topicIDs=[demo134001007467618]}
```

Now how should I get each value from the list so that I can assign them on my local vars?

```
//Full block of code
public void pubsub() throws Exception {
       String topic = "demo" + System.nanoTime();
       Stream<Map<String, Object>> sub = ipfs.pubsub.sub(topic);
       String data = "Hello!";
       Object pub = ipfs.pubsub.pub(topic, data);
       Object pub2 = ipfs.pubsub.pub(topic, "G'day");
       List<Map> results = sub.limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());
       results.stream().filter(s->s.containsKey("data")).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: why do you want them to assign local variables?

Comment: I just need to be able to get each of the fields and assign it on a variable so that I can return it and continue my flow. `String a = SGVsbG8h a.decodeBase64`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the parsing issue:

```
 public void pubsub2() throws Exception {
        String topic = "demo" + System.nanoTime();
        Stream<Map<String, Object>> sub = ipfs.pubsub.sub(topic); 
        String data = "Hello!"; 
        Object pub = ipfs.pubsub.pub(topic, data); 
        Object pub2 = ipfs.pubsub.pub(topic, "G'day"); 
        List<Map> results = sub.limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());

   for (int index = 0; index< results.size(); index++ ) {
            Map<String, String> listItem = results.get(index);
            System.out.println(listItem);
            Iterator it = listItem.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" = " + pair.getValue());
                }
```